# Unable to send variable from flash(parent) to loaded flex swf(child)?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, communication

Hai am trying to load the variables from parent(flash) to child(flash).Its working fine,.

**parent swf:**(flash)

```
var parentMessage:String = "Hello";
var swf:MovieClip;
var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
l.load(new URLRequest("child.swf"));
function swfLoaded(e:Event):void
{
swf = MovieClip(e.target.content);
swf.passVariable(parentMessage);
}
```

**child swf**(flex)

```
public var childMessage:String;
function passVariable(_msg:String):void
{
childMessage = _msg;
trace("message passed from parent to child: " + childMessage);
}
```

But while communicating with flash to flex its not loaded.

**Error Message**

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property passVariable not found on
>   _child_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value.   at Function/()

Kindly help me .

**Update**

**parent.swf** in flash

```
 var parentMessage:String = "Hello";
 var swf:MovieClip;
 var l:Loader = new Loader();
 l.load(new URLRequest("asd.swf"));
 swf.addEventListener("applicationComplete", swfLoaded);
 function swfLoaded(e:Event):void
 {
 var app:DisplayObject = swf.getChildAt(1);
 app["passVariable"](parentMessage);
 }
```

Child.swf in flex

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"  addedToStage="application1_addedHandler(event)" >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var childMessage:String;

        protected function application1_addedHandler(event:Event):void
        {

            passVariable(childMessage);
        }
        public function passVariable(_msg:String):void
        {

            childMessage = _msg;
            trace("First message passed from parent to child: " + childMessage);
}

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

**ErrorMessage**

```
   TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
   TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.managers::FocusManager/activate()
at spark.components::Application/initManagers()
at spark.components::Application/initialize()
at asd/initialize()
at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/childAdded()
at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()
at       mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex applications top most sprite is `SystemManager`. And `Application` object is added as a child of `SystemManager`. So, you'll need to get it.

```
swf = MovieClip(e.target.content);
swf.addEventListener("applicationComplete", onApplicationReady);

private function onApplicationReady(evt:Event)
{
    var app:DisplayObject = swf.getChildAt(0);
    app["passVariable"](...);
}
```

Note, that `Application` is added on "`applicationComplete`" event.

Read more about [loading applications](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/loading_applications.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Am getting error like this,1061: Call to a possibly undefined method passVariable through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: @user1268367 I've updated the answer. You can use dynamic property.

Comment: Again am getting error,ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property passVariable not found on _ViewPPT_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value.
 at Function/<anonymous>()

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing one of two things:

1. You're not waiting until the swf is fully loaded before you try to cast it
2. You didn't compile the swf's Class into the Flex file (but this should give you a compiler error)

The second problem is actually a good problem to have--Your Flex file doesn't need to know about the *implementation* of the methods it will call, just the *contract* (or Interface) of those methods).

Regardless of which problem you have, [this example](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/01/example-of-casting-contets-of-swfloader.html), which shows casting a loaded swf to an Interface and calling methods on it, should help.

Comment: The text in blue ("this example") is what is known as a "hyperlink," which you might not be aware is actually clickable text that will take you to another place. In this case, it takes you to a blog post where you can get to the View Source enabled example.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/06/call-function-from-flex-to-flash/

Load the AS3 swf file using an instance of SWFLoader.

Call the function like this:

mySWFLoader.content.functionName();

How to listen for flash events from flex?

```
// In your Flex app
/* called when your SWFLoader finishes loading the SWF */
private function onMySWFLoaded( p_event:Event ) :void
{
      mySWFLoader.content.addEventListener( “clicked”, onSWFClick );
}
/* callback for the clicked event */
private function onSWFClick( event:Event ) :void
{
      mx.controls.Alert.show( ‘Click event raised!’ );
}
```

// In Flash Movie

```
/* called when the button in your flash movie is clicked */
private function onButtonClick( p_event:Event ) :void
{
      dispatchEvent( new Event( “clicked” );
}
```

How to call a flex function from flash at a specific frame?

```
Embed(source=“../assets/swf/myFlashComponent.swf”, symbol=“Preloader”)]
private var FlashPreloaderSymbol:Class;
private var clip:MovieClip;
clip = new FlashPreloaderSymbol();
addChild(clip);
private function onFlexInitComplete( event:FlexEvent ):void
{
clip.addFrameScript(47, callMyFunction);
}
```

Comment: i need to pass the variable from flash(parent) to flex(child) (ie i load the swf in flash)

Answer (score 0):

All I can see is that the flex function is not public.

This prevents other classes from seeing it.

Change the definition to

```
public function passVariable(_msg:String):void
```

**EDIT**
Extending my comment,

A better way would be to loop over all children of swf, and if the `passVariable` function exists in that, call it.

```
function swfLoaded(e:Event):void {
    for each(var app:DisplayObject in swf.getChildren()) {
        if(app.passVariable != null) {
            app["passVariable"](parentMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: am trying  public function also,TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at mx.managers::FocusManager/activate()

mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 
 at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()

message passed from parent to child: null

Comment: Why don't you debug your code? Is `swf.getChildAt(1) ;` returning the intended Flex Object? A better way would be to (see my edited answer)